# What sets the __debug__ variable in a production Django / WSGI based site?

Tags: django, debugging, settings

The python documentation defines a global constant named __debug__ :

> **__debug__**
>
> This constant is true if Python was not started with an -O option. See also the assert statement.

I'm using some python library under my production Django site (Apache/WSGI based) which checks this constant before executing debug-only code.To my surprise, that code is being executed in production.

As the Django site was not started via the python command line interperter, I was wondering what controls this __deubg__ constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use the [PYTHONOPTIMIZE](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE) environment variable. You may need to set it from your apache configuration... Not too sure I haven't used the standard WSGI setup in a long time.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my problem too. All I had to do was "export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1" before running "manage.py runserver"

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of all who follow, this is the wsgi directive you are looking for: [WSGIPythonOptimize](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonOptimize)

The documentation states:

```
The default is '0' which means no optimisations are applied.
```

So in the default case `__debug__` would be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `settings.DEBUG` set to `False`?

Comment: Yes. It seems to have no effect.